# How can I serve another site on a different local IP address?

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, reverse-proxy

Okay so what I'm trying to achieve here are the followings:

I have `example.com` running on `172.31.1.90` natted to ports `80 and 443`, and it is working as it is supposed to

I would like to reach a page via `subdomain.example.com` but it should be served on another apache server in the same internal network running on `172.31.1.65:80` Is it possible to do somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the ports `80` and `443` are already port forwarded in the NAT to `172.31.1.90`, and it's unlikely the router could terminate the HTTP(S) protocol, handling the `Host` header (or SNI), you could use the `172.31.1.90` as a [*reverse proxy*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) to the `172.31.1.65:80`, e.g.:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName subdomain.example.com 
    ProxyPass / http://172.31.1.65/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://172.31.1.65/ 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!
Thank you sir!